# Crawl and index file server - is it possible to read metadata from the document in SharePoint columns?

Tags: crawl, file-server, content-enrichment

I want to make the content of a "normal" Windows file server available in the full text search in SharePoint 2013 or newer.

This is possible by crawling and indexing the directories on the file server with Sharepoint.

How can I read document properties of each crawled Word or PDF document and put them into a metadata column in SharePoint (and then use it for search refiners)?
(it is possible to create custom document properties in MS Word and therefore it could be possible to use them as metadata in Sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create custom properties in the word file. Please follow the below steps to create a custom property in the word file:

- Right-click on the particular word file.
- Click on the "**Custom**" tab.
- In the "**Name**" column enter the property name.
- In the "**Type**" column select the data type.
- In the "**Value**" box, enter the property value.
- Click on the "**Add**" button
- Finally, click on the "**Apply**" and "**Ok**" button

Below is the example:

[image: CreateCustomPropertyInWordFile.JPG]

After crawling the file share, we can map these properties with SharePoint managed properties, then we can use those manage properties in the search refiner.

Comment: Hi - if the above answer helps you, could you please mark as answered, it will help to the upcoming visitors for the similar issues, thanks for the understanding :-)